# File Upload button flickering using mousenter and mouseleave with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Having a little trouble with a file upload button. I can't for the life of me get the mouseenter and mouseover effects to function without flickering.

I think it is probably something fairly straightforward but I am a bit of a jquery novice.

Here is the fiddle:

jsfiddle.net/dingobruce/tdgn2/4/

The jquery:

```
$(function(){
    var btnUpload=$('#upload_main');
    new AjaxUpload(btnUpload); });
$( "#upload_main" ).mouseenter(function() {
$( "#upload_main" ).addClass("upload_button_on" );});
$( "#upload_main" ).mouseleave(function() {
$( "#upload_main" ).removeClass("upload_button_on" );});
```

And the html code:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="upload_main" class="upload_button">
Upload
</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.upload_button {
 border-color:#DADADA;
 color:#000000;
 border-width:1px;
 border-style:solid;
 font-family:'gothic_bold';
 font-size:13px;
 background:#ECECEC;
 text-align:center;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 padding:5px;
 width:115px;
}

.upload_button_on {
 color:#FFFFFF;
 background:#000;
 text-decoration:none;
 border-color:#000000;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

Any help or pointers greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

dingobruce

Comment: Post code _on_ the site. And works fine for me. What browser you using?

Comment: Not quite sure how I can add the code now. I have a fairly old Macbook Pro so running old browsers Safari 5.01 and Firefox 12.0. Neither seem to function properly.

Comment: I just tested Safari and Chrome. They all good. Try wrapping the `<a>` with a `<span>` though. And just press the "Edit" to edit your post

Comment: Hello Idris, I did something rather foolish and posted the wrong fiddle. I have updated it now to the correct fiddle, which is trimmed down to just the essentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code is functional, however is conflicting with the `AjaxUpload` plugin you're using.

There is a hover class being added by the plugin, you can use that to appy your styles -  [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tdgn2/16/)

Change `.upload_button_on` to `.hover` in your CSS

```
.hover {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-color:#000000;
    cursor:pointer;
 }
```